# How to configure smart proxy in Nexus Repository Manager 3?

Tags: nexus

Smart proxy in Nexus Repository manager 2 was very straightforward according to [this documentation](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/smartproxy-enabling_smart_proxy_publishing.html).

It isn't the case in Nexus Repository manager 3 any more, and there's only a minimal amount of information regrading to the smart proxy feature in the [version 3 documentation](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference3/index.html). There is also no sigh that the feature is available in the capabilities list.

Any idea how this should be configured?

Answer (score 2):

Just confirmed by sonatype that this is not implemented in Nexus 3 and will be replaced by new function called Component Fabric

Details written in [Nexus Repository Manager Feature Compatibility Matrix](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/222426568-Nexus-Repository-Manager-Feature-Compatibility-Matrix).